# Borel Cantelli liminf of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a succession of indepedent random variables, such that for all $n\geq 1$, $\mathbb E(X_n) =0$ and $\mathbb E(|X_n|) = 1$,

Prove or disprove that $\mathbb P(\lim \inf_{n} X_n < 0) > 0.$

I tried to handle it like this

Let us consider the succession of events $A_n = \{X_n < 0\}$. Since $(X_n)_n$ are independent then $(A_n)_n$  and $A^c_n = \{X_n \geq 0\}$ are also indepedent events. We have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\lim \inf_{n} X_n < 0) &= \mathbb P(\lim \inf_{n} A_n)\\
& = \mathbb P(A_n \, \text{ e.v.})\\
&= 1 - \mathbb P\big((A_n \, \text{ e.v.})^c\big)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb P(A_n^c \, \text{ i.o.}\big).
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A_n^c) &= \mathbb P(X_n \geq 0)\\ 
& = ...
\end{align*}

Here some recall of the notations used and my intention is to use the second BorelCantelli lemma that also I recall it here

First let's recall some definitions. Let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of events, we define
\begin{align*}
A_{n} \text{ infinitely often (i.o.) } &\equiv\left\{\omega: \omega \text { is in infinitely many } A_{n}\right\}\equiv \limsup _{n} A_{n} \equiv \bigcap_{m}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty} A_{n}
\end{align*}

Note that
$$
\mathbb {I}_{A_{n} \,i.o. }=\lim_{n} \sup \mathbb{I}_{A_{n}}
$$
Similarly, 
\begin{align*}
 A_{n}\text{ eventually (e.v.) } 
 \equiv\left\{\omega: \omega \text { is in } A_{n} \text { for all large } n\right\} 
 \equiv \liminf _{n} A_{n}
 \equiv \bigcup_{m} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} A_{n}.
\end{align*}
Note that
$$
\mathbb{I}_{A_{n} \,e.v.} =\liminf _{n} \mathbb{I}_{A_{n}}
$$
Also we have $\left(A_{n} \text { e.v.}\right)^{c}=\left(A_{n}^{c} \text { i.o. }\right)$. 
Moreover recall the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma:

If the events $(A_n)_n$ are independent, then $\sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(A_{n})=\infty$ implies $\mathbb{P}(A_{n} \text{ i.o.})=1$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please look to my update

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $e.v.$, what do you mean by it?

Comment: ah sorry e.v. to note eventually and i.o.  infinitely often. I will update with a recall of Second Borela-Cantelli Lemma

Comment: I am familiar with the notation 'i.o', but not with 'e.v'.

Comment: Two things seem wrong: (1) Your claim $P[(\liminf_n X_n) < 0] = P[\liminf_n A_n]$ (since we can have $A_n$ true always but $\liminf_n X_n=0$, consider the example $X_n=-1/n$ for all $n$); (2) Actually we can get an example where $A_n$ occurs finitely often with prob 1, even when $E[|X_n|]=1$, $E[X_n]=0$, $\{X_n\}$ indep.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your corrections., so you disprove this statement

Comment: You should clarify if you mean $P[(\liminf_n X_n) < 0]$ or $P[\liminf_n \{X_n<0\}]$.

Comment: it's $\mathbb P[(\lim\inf_n X_n) < 0]$. sorry for this ambiguity.

Comment: @Michael please could you try to put your answer for this statement.

Comment: It might be to use the notation of $P[\lim\inf_n \{X_n >0\}].$ This is more convenient to use Borela-Cantelli Lemma

Comment: Just get an example where $X_n\neq 0$ finitely often.

Answer (score 1):

Design $X_n \in \{-b_n, 0, b_n\}$ for $n \in \{1, 2 ,3, ...\}$ to satisfy

(i) $X_n \neq 0$ finitely often (with prob 1);

(ii) $E[X_n]=0$ for all $n$;

(iii) $E[|X_n|]=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am wondering how $\mathbb E[|X_n|] = 1$, I think it's $2/3$ since there is equiprobability between the realizations of $X_n$, meaning $\mathbb P[X_n=-b_n] = \mathbb P[X_n=0] = \mathbb P[X_n = b_n] = 1/3$. In this case $E[|X_n]| = 2/3$.

Comment: Who said $P[X_n=-b_n]=P[X_n=0] = P[X_n=b_n]$?  Surely not!  You can never get $P[\{X_n \neq 0\} f.o.]=1$ that way. I mentioned "Design $X_n$" and so there are a few things left to design (such as the PMF). (And the specific $b_n$ values). I think the structure $X_n \in \{-b_n, 0, b_n\}$ should be suggestive enough to complete the steps.

Comment: Anyway, even if $P[X_n=-b_n]=P[X_n=0]=P[X_n=b_n]=1/3$, you cannot claim $E[|X_n|]=2/3$ without specifying the value of $b_n$. You would only get $2/3$ in the special case when $b_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: In your terminology, you want $$P[\{X_n=0\} \: \mbox{eventually}] = 1$$ where I believe you are using "$\{X_n=0\}$ eventually" to mean that "$X_n=0$ for all but a finite number of indices $n \in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$."  (This is equivalent to my condition (i)  above).